# Magento - > I want the product grid in admin to be displayed in frontend

Tags: php, mysql, magento, jqgrid, entity-attribute-value

I want the grid in admin to be displayed in frontend.
The grid that shows the list of products in admin-> catalog->manage products.

I want to show this on the frontend for each category?

What would be ideal approach to get this done?

Comment: Do you found any solution. I am having same requirement

Comment: Have you did it or not ? 
I have to develop same
please share with us also if you developed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite blocks

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
```

to your own, because in this classes we have logic for editing, adding products.

also you need to redefine

```
adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml
adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
```

and add templates to the frontend scope with your customizations.

add to the frontend catalog.xml blocks declaration for catalog_category_default node
it might be like this:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block name="module_name/catalog_product_grid" template="module_name/catalog_product_grid.phtml" output="toHtml />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: you don't really need to rewrite the base admin classes.  you *can* just overload them in your own derived grid class (which is how you should be doing things anyways) -- you do need to copy the templates to the frontend template folders, which is what the aforementioned answer i think means when it says "redefine"

Comment: Can you be a lil more specific plz, it is too general answer.

Answer (score 2):

Extending admin block classes in your module and copy widgets template files from adminhtml allowing adminhtml display in frontend, but you need to load required javascripts and CSS to allow grid works and you'd be pay attention to conflicts.
Probably it's more easy to using a thirdy part ajax grid in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with emalstyle.

You can get the data from a collection, convert collection data to js object and implement a widget like:

https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/datagrid/